# issues with the code I am working on. It is about a pong game

Tags: python

I've been trying to solve this for a while now but I keep getting this error. I am using VS code and Python version 3.11. I trying using IDLE, and Spyder, but I still have this error. Anyone know how to solve it? I uninstalled all the libraries and installed them again, but it didn't work.

Here's the code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    # Hyperparameters
    H = 200  # number of hidden layer neurons
    learning_rate = 1e-4
    gamma = 0.99  # discount factor for reward
    decay_rate = 0.99  # decay factor for RMSProp leaky sum of grad^2
    batch_size = 10 # Amount of episodes to do an update
    num_train_episodes = 1000
    
    # Define the policy network
    class PolicyNetwork(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super(PolicyNetwork, self).__init__()
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(80 * 80, H)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(H, 1)
            self.relu = nn.ReLU()
            self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
    
        def forward(self, x):
            x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
            return self.sigmoid(self.fc2(x))
    
    
    def prepro(I):
        """ Preprocess 210x160x3 uint8 frame into 6400 (80x80) 1D float vector """
        I = I[35:195]  # Crop
        I = I[::2, ::2, 0]  # Downsample by factor of 2
        I[I == 144] = 0  # Erase background (background type 1)
        I[I == 109] = 0  # Erase background (background type 2)
        I[I != 0] = 1  # Everything else (paddles, ball) just set to 1
        return I.astype(np.float64).ravel()
    
    
    def discount_rewards(r):
        """ Take 1D float array of rewards and compute discounted reward """
        discounted_r = np.zeros_like(r)
        running_add = 0
        for t in reversed(range(0, r.size)):
            if r[t] != 0:
                running_add = 0  # Reset the sum, since this was a game boundary (pong specific!)
            running_add = running_add * gamma + r[t]
            discounted_r[t] = running_add
        return discounted_r
    
    
    """
    # Print model's state_dict
    print("Model's state_dict:")
    for param_tensor in policy_network.state_dict():
        print(param_tensor, "\t", policy_network.state_dict()[param_tensor].size())
    """
    def train(policy_network, optimizer, env, batch_size=10, gamma=0.99, resume=False):
        # Initialize environment
        observation = env.reset()
        prev_x = None  # Used in computing the difference frame
        xs, hs, dlogps, drs = [], [], [], []
        running_reward = None
        reward_sum = 0
        episode_number = 0
        episode_rewards = []
        resume = False
    
        if resume:
            policy_network.load_state_dict(torch.load('policy_checkpoint.pth'))
            policy_network.eval()
            
        while True:
            # Preprocess the observation, set input to network to be difference image
            cur_x = prepro(observation)
            x = torch.tensor(cur_x - prev_x if prev_x is not None else np.zeros_like(cur_x), dtype=torch.float32)
            prev_x = cur_x
    
            # Forward pass the policy network and sample an action from the returned probability
            aprob = policy_network(x)
            action = 2 if np.random.uniform() < aprob.item() else 3  # Roll the dice!
    
            # Record various intermediates (needed later for backprop)
            xs.append(x)  # Observation
            hs.append(x)  # Hidden state
            y = torch.tensor([1 if action == 2 else 0], dtype=torch.float32)  # A "fake label"
            dlogps.append(y - aprob)  # Grad that encourages the action that was taken to be taken
    
            # Step the environment and get new measurements
            observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
            reward_sum += reward
    
            drs.append(reward)  # Record reward
    
            if done:  # An episode finished
                episode_number += 1
    
                # Stack together all inputs, hidden states, action gradients, and rewards for this episode
                epx = torch.stack(xs)
                epdlogp = torch.stack(dlogps)
                epr = torch.tensor(discount_rewards(np.vstack(drs)), dtype=torch.float32)
                xs, hs, dlogps, drs = [], [], [], []  # Reset array memory
    
                # Discount and normalize rewards
                discounted_epr = (epr - epr.mean()) / (epr.std() + 1e-8)
                epdlogp *= discounted_epr  # Modulate the gradient with advantage
                optimizer.zero_grad()
    
                # Backward pass
                loss = torch.sum(-epdlogp)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
    
                # Save model
                if episode_number % batch_size == 0:
                    torch.save(policy_network.state_dict(), 'policy_checkpoint.pth')
                    print(policy_network.state_dict())
                episode_rewards.append(reward_sum)
                # Boring book-keeping
                running_reward = reward_sum if running_reward is None else running_reward * 0.99 + reward_sum * 0.01
                print('Resetting env. Episode reward total was %.2f. Running mean: %.2f' % (reward_sum, running_reward))
                reward_sum = 0
                observation = env.reset()  # Reset environment
                prev_x = None
    
            if reward != 0:  # Pong has either +1 or -1 reward exactly when game ends
                print('Ep {}: Game finished, reward: {}'.format(episode_number, reward) + ('' if reward == -1 else ' !!!!!!!!'))
    
            if episode_number >= 1000:  # stopping criteria
                break
        return episode_rewards
    
    def plot_results(episode_rewards):
        plt.plot(episode_rewards)
        plt.title('Episode rewards over time')
        plt.xlabel('Episode')
        plt.ylabel('Total reward')
        plt.show()
    
    # Create environment
    render = False
    env = gym.make("Pong-v0") if not render else gym.make("Pong-v0", render_mode='human')
    
    # Initialize policy network and optimizer
    policy_network = PolicyNetwork()
    optimizer = optim.RMSprop(policy_network.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, alpha=decay_rate)
    
    # Train the policy network
    train_rewards = train(policy_network, optimizer, env, batch_size, gamma, num_train_episodes)
    
    # Plotting
    plot_results(train_rewards)
    
    Here's the error:
    FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[2], line 157
        155 # Create environment
        156 render = False
    --> 157 env = gym.make("Pong-v0") if not render else gym.make("Pong-v0", render_mode='human')
        159 # Initialize policy network and optimizer
        160 policy_network = PolicyNetwork()
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Don't make us retype your code from an image.  Post your code and the full error message as plain text.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but this code won't generate the error you show. It will give an `IndentationError`. Please make sure to copy your code _exactly_. We can't be expected to guess at which errors are relevant and which are typos. The easiest way to share code here is to paste it, then select it and click the code button in the toolbar.